# Example of a measure so that the outer measures obtained with Proposition 1.10 in Folland are strictly smaller than the measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Outer measure is defined as follows in Folland, and one way to obtain it is presented in Proposition 1.10.
[image]
[image]

First, I think there is a typo in this proposition, and $\rho$ should be $\mu$.
Second, For every set $A$, $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A)$ is held because we can define $E_1=A$ and $E_j=\emptyset ; j\ge2$.

Can anyone make an example for measure $\mu$ so that, for an arbitrary set $A$, $\mu^*(A) \neq \mu(A)$ or equivalently $\mu^*(A) < \mu(A)$ are held when the outer measure is obtained by Proposition 1.10?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that's a typo. It should be $\rho$ rather than $\mu$, although this is not reflected in the [errata](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Efolland/Homepage/reals.pdf) for the book.

You cannot find a measure for which $\mu^* (A) \neq \mu (A)$ or $\mu^* (A) < \mu (A)$ for arbitrary $A$, because $\mu$ is defined by  $\mu (A) = \mu^* (A)$ for $A$ which are $\mu^*$-measurable (recall that we say $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if $\mu^* (E) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A^c \cap E)$ for all $E \subset X$).

Comment: Okay, so would you give me an example of $\mu$ and a set $A$ which is not $\mu^*$-measurable so that $\mu^*(A)<\mu(A)$?

Comment: @khashayar Sure. If you set $X = [0,1]$ and $\mathcal{E} = \{ \emptyset , X \}$, then $[0,0.5]$ is not $\mu^*$-measurable.